# How to import appear.js in webpack-encore?

Tags: symfony4, webpack-encore

I installed with yarn add appear. But the import with `import 'appear';` not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

webpack.config.js:

```
Encore
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

assets/js/app.js:

```
// could add css here too

require('appear'); // might be necessary to add path like with fontawesome '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
```

twig template css:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

twig template js:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```